# how to put the icon on the right in android table layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use tablelayout instead of the custom header title bar

Now my layout like the xml I show below, and I want to put the 2 icon and the text align right, but when I use `android:layout_gravity="right"` it seems not work, so how can I do it ?

This is my layout xml:

```
  < ? xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  < LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >    
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#4494D1" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView

                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:text="简易尺子" 
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="25dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                         android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" 

                    >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="28dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/android2"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="关于"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                        android:layout_width="28dp"
                        android:layout_height="28dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/programs" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="帮助"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </SurfaceView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layout gravity you set is not to affect the positioning of the `TextView` and the `ImageView` in the TableRow, rather it will position them in the wrapping `LinearLayout` which is not quite what you need. I suggest you define the following attribute to your `TableLayout`:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="0,1">
```

This will make the first two columns of the raw expand and thus shrink the rightmost column to the right.

**NOTE (IMPORTANT)** Currently you do not have a valid layout defined: you have a `TableRow` in `LinearLayout` - this is not allowed - you should place the row in `TableLayout` like the one I have defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:text="简易尺子"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="28dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButton2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text2"
                    android:text="关于"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:layout_width="28dp"
                    android:layout_height="28dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton2"
                    android:text="帮助"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1" >
    </SurfaceView>

</RelativeLayout>
```